# django 2.2.21 file path

Tags: django, pytest-django

since django did this security issue

https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2021/may/04/security-releases/

iam not able to open file for test data:
iam using

```
import os
from django.core.files import File
file = File(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "data", "tests", "test_pdf.pdf"))
```

then

```
Model.objects.create(name="test". file=file)
```

getting error:

```
 django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: File name 'apps/app/data/tests/test_pdf.pdf' includes path elements
```

any workaroud of this? or whats a correct way to load the pdf?

Comment: The bug is now fixed in the django releases made today, May 13th, 2.23, versions 2.2.23, 3.1.11, 3.2.3

Answer (score 2):

duplicate of [Getting error "SuspiciousFileOperation" after Django Version Update Django: 3.1.9 from Django: 3.1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399787/getting-error-suspiciousfileoperation-after-django-version-update-django-3-1/67407722#67407722)

(the workaround is to add `name="test_pdf.pdf"` as a kwarg to your File() constructor.)

edit: The bug is now fixed in the django releases made today, May 13th, 2.23, versions 2.2.23, 3.1.11, 3.2.3

Comment: totaly missed this one, thanks very much!